# How to convert regclass to string without quotes?

Tags: postgresql, formatting

I have stored procedure:

```
create or replace function make_bi_temporal( _tbl regclass )
returns void as $$
BEGIN
execute format( 'alter table %s drop constraint if exists %s_pkey', _tbl, _tbl );
...
```

But I get the error when run `select make_bi_temporal( 'check' )`

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "_pkey"
LINE 1: alter table "check" drop constraint if exists "check"_pkey
```

I tried to change `%s` to `%I`:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "_pkey"
LINE 1: ...ter table "check" drop constraint if exists """check"""_pkey
```

to `%L`:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "'"check"'"
LINE 1: alter table "check" drop constraint if exists '"check"'_pkey
```

I want to get `check_pkey`.

How to format without quotes?

Comment: Try `%s` and `_tbl::text`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: any convertion regclass to text gives me quotes =(  `select cast( 'check'::regclass as text )`, `_tbl || '_pkey'` etc.

Comment: How exactly are you calling the function? Looks OK to me: https://rextester.com/HVMCN53576

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: try to use `check` instead of `foo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first mistake was to create a table with the name `check`, which is a [reserved keyword](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/sql-keywords-appendix.html).

```
create table check( id int primary key);
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "check"
LINE 1: create table check( id int primary key);
```

You or someone else must have bypassed this  by quoting it.

```
create table "check"( id int primary key);
```

So, it would create a primary key constraint with a name `"check_pkey"`.

Your method of *stripping the quotes* from a `regclass` doesn't sound like a proper solution but rather a work-around.

Since you need the text representation of a `regclass`, you simply query `pg_class`.

```
create or replace function make_bi_temporal( _tbl regclass )
returns void as $$
declare
 l_relname pg_class.relname%type;
BEGIN
   select relname||'_pkey' into l_relname from pg_class where oid = $1;
   execute format( 'alter table %s drop constraint if exists %s',$1,l_relname);
END $$ language plpgsql;
```

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=5e596106bd2ec956dd83f2062d9012d4)

Comment: Also found this solution: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/141680/91706

Answer (score 1):

Seems found solution via regex:

```
regexp_replace( _tbl::text, '"', '', 'g' )


execute format( 'alter table %s drop constraint if exists %s_pkey', _tbl, regexp_replace( _tbl::text, '"', '', 'g' ) );
```

I use this just as workaround, because this seems is not correct way of doing that